# static side menu scroll in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using admin template from http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin-v2/ but I found that if side menu items get more than page hight there is no scroll, how can I add scroll to static side menu when menu items or page height is changed?
like http://responsiweb.com/themes/preview/ace/1.3/

You may change your browser height to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a scroll plugin [like niceScroll](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/) and use this code:

```
var sideMenuCheck = function () {
    var ss = $("#side-menu");
    ss.css({
        'height': ss.height() + 'px'
    });

    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    document.body.style.overflow = "";

    var menuParent = ss.parent();   

        menuParent.css({
            'height': (viewportHeight - 50) + 'px',
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        });

    menuParent.niceScroll();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    sideMenuCheck();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    sideMenuCheck();

});
```

*Note: This answer was posted on behalf of the OP.*

Comment: Isn't there a way to just make the whole page longer and not rely on yet another javascript library?